# (object) does not name a type. Whats going on?

Tags: c++

I think the code shows the problem best

```
class blok
{ public:
    sf::RectangleShape TenBlok;
    int x,y;
    blok(int posX ,int posY)
 {
     x = posX;
     y = posY;
 }
 void place(int x,int y)
 {
        TenBlok.setPosition((float)x,(float)y)
 }
};
```

[...]

```
class Trawa : public blok
{

int id = 0;
sf::Texture tekstura;
tekstura.loadFromFile("trawa.png"); //<---- here it says "tekstura does not name a type"
TenBlok.setTexture(tekstura); //<---- here it says "TenBlok does not name a type"

};
```

Error says that the object doesnt name a type, but oddly enough CodeBlocks sees bother tekstura and TenBlok as vaild objects becouse id hints functions those objects contain

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use statements

```
tekstura.loadFromFile("trawa.png"); //<---- here it says "tekstura does not name a type"
TenBlok.setTexture(tekstura); //<---- here it says "TenBlok does not name a type"
```

in the class definition. They are not declarations. You can have such statements inside the definition of a member function, but not the class itself.

A simpler class that will fail with similar errors:

```
struct Foo
{
   int i;
   i = 10;
};
```

To initialize `i` (or execute similar statements), use a constructor.

```
struct Foo
{
   int i;
   Foo() { i = 10; }  // For demonstration. It will be better to initialize
                      // i using Foo() : i(10) {}
};
```

For you class, you probably need:

```
class Trawa : public blok
{
   int id = 0;
   sf::Texture tekstura;

   Trawa() : blok(0, 0)  // Assume position to be (0, 0)
   {
      tekstura.loadFromFile("trawa.png");
      TenBlok.setTexture(tekstura);
   }
};
```